# How to write Flutter widget test for a widget that uses the Connectivity plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a single screen that uses the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package from the Flutter dev team. I am able to build golden images for this widget when I don't use the connectivity package, but when I add it the way that is outlined by the Flutter dev team on their page on pub.dev, I encounter exceptions when running the tests via the `flutter test --update-goldens` command.

I have included the test file (**test/widget/widget_test.dart**), **main.dart**, **welcome_screen.dart**, and the output from running the tests. I tried looking for similar issues that others have experienced online, but my efforts were not fruitful; I am looking for help in resolving this issue. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

## Output

from `flutter test --update-goldens`

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel
plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown running a test:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method check on channel
plugins.flutter.io/connectivity)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
...

The test description was:
  WelcomeScreen Golden test
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:04 +14 -1: /Users/---/Documents/---/---/---/test/widget/widget_test.dart: WelcomeScreen Golden test [E]                                                                                                                      
  Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: WelcomeScreen Golden test
  
00:04 +14 -1: Some tests failed.
```

## Test: widget_test.dart

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('WelcomeScreen Golden test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    await expectLater(
      find.byType(MyApp),
      matchesGoldenFile('main.png'),
    );
  });
}
```

## main.dart

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
        routes: {
          WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
          DashboardScreen.id: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Screen: welcome_screen.dart

```dart
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';

  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  
  ConnectivityResult _connectionStatus = ConnectivityResult.none;
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  String username = '';
  String password = '';
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _connectivitySubscription = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
    initConnectivity();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
            RoundedTextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              placeholder: 'Username',
              icon: Icons.person,
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  username = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            RoundedTextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              placeholder: 'Password',
              icon: Icons.lock,
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              password: true,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  password = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            isLoading
                ? Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22.0),
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
                : RoundedButton(
                    disabled: isLoading,
                    title: 'Log In',
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    onPressed: (_connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.mobile || _connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.wifi)
                        ? () async {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = true;
                            });
                            try {
                              Login login = await API().login(username, password);
                              if (login.appUserKey != 0) {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, DashboardScreen.id);
                              }
                            } catch (e) {
                              print(e);
                            }
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = false;
                            });
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    ConnectivityResult result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return Future.value(null);
    }

    return _updateConnectionStatus(result);
  }

  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Connected to network'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Disconnected from network'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
      default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = null);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Connectivity failed'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the resolution to this might involve somehow mocking the "listen" method in the connectivity plugin, because the environment in which the tests run is a platform that the plugin does not anticipate, and therefore doesn't have a way of listening to the connectivity status of the device. This issue is still not resolved for me, but I will continue trying to fix the problems I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

The widget was trying to run a method that did not exist for the platform on which the tests were being run. I decided to mock the Connectivity class, send the mocked class to the widget, and then have the widget itself check to see what *type* of class it had received in order to determine if it should attempt to run the *listen* method; the method whose invocation had previously been causing exceptions to be thrown. I used the [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package to easily mock the service.

I've included the relevant code snippets that resolved the issue for me.

## Test: widget_test.dart

*Important: Used [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) to mock the Connectivity class*

```dart
class MockConnectivity extends Mock implements Connectivity {}

void main() {
  testWidgets('WelcomeScreen', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: WelcomeScreen(
            connectivity: MockConnectivity(),
          ),
        ),
      );
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });

    await expectLater(
      find.byType(WelcomeScreen),
      matchesGoldenFile('welcome_screen_portrait.png'),
    );
  });
}
```

## main.dart

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(
          connectivity: Connectivity(),
        ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## welcome_screen.dart

```dart
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';
  final Connectivity connectivity;
  WelcomeScreen({this.connectivity});

  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  Connectivity _connectivity;
  ConnectivityResult _connectionStatus = ConnectivityResult.none;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _connectivity = widget.connectivity;
    if (_connectivity.runtimeType == Connectivity) {
      _connectivitySubscription = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
    }
    initConnectivity();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    if (_connectivity.runtimeType == Connectivity) {
      _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('Welcome'),
    );
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    ConnectivityResult result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return Future.value(null);
    }

    return _updateConnectionStatus(result);
  }

  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Connected to network'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Disconnected from network'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
      default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = null);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Connectivity failed'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```